# Recording HTTPS web pages using web page replay

Tags: python-2.7, http, ssl, https, chromium

I'm trying to record websites for an experiment using [web-page-replay](https://github.com/chromium/web-page-replay). Recording HTTP requests works fine, but when I try to record HTTPS requests, I get an SSLError.

On OSX, I'm using this command to record web pages

```
sudo ./replay.py --record archive.wpr
```

I have set the system HTTP Proxy to localhost:80 and HTTPS Proxy to localhost:443

Traceback -

```
2015-02-24 03:57:26,227 ERROR Client failed to make request
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 63226)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/akshay/Projects/web-page-replay/httpproxy.py", line 162, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 714, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 608, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
SSLError: [SSL: HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST] https proxy request (_ssl.c:1750)
----------------------------------------
```

**Update** - I tried recording pagesets using [telemetry](http://www.chromium.org/developers/telemetry/run_locally) and got SSL Handshake error when recording https pages.

```
2015-03-01 11:12:04,929 WARNING HTTP server started on 127.0.0.1:50781
2015-03-01 11:12:04,930 WARNING HTTPS server started on 127.0.0.1:50782
2015-03-01 11:12:04,981 ERROR Client failed to make request
2015-03-01 11:12:04,981 ERROR Client failed to make request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/akshay/Downloads/telemetry/src/third_party/webpagereplay/httpproxy.py", line 162, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 714, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 608, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
SSLError: [SSL: SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl handshake failure (_ssl.c:1750)
2015-03-01 11:12:05,782 ERROR Client failed to make request
2015-03-01 11:12:07,611 WARNING Retrying fetch GET https://www.google.com/ [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:08,844 WARNING Retrying fetch GET https://www.google.com/ [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:09,539 WARNING Retrying fetch GET https://www.google.com/ [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:10,146 CRITICAL Could not fetch GET https://www.google.com/ [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:11,386 WARNING Retrying fetch GET https://www.google.com/favicon.ico [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:13,428 WARNING Retrying fetch GET https://www.google.com/favicon.ico [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:14,417 WARNING Retrying fetch GET https://www.google.com/favicon.ico [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
2015-03-01 11:12:18,349 CRITICAL Could not fetch GET https://www.google.com/favicon.ico [('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, '), ('host', 'www.google.com')]: hostname '74.125.236.209' doesn't match 'www.google.com'
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50785)
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: It looks like `web-page-replay` is operating in transparent proxy mode. What happens if you do not set explicit HTTP/HTTPs proxies in Chrome?

Comment: No, it doesn't record anything if the proxy isn't set explicitly. This diagram explains how WPR records and replays the requests.

Comment: Understood - I looked closer at the documentation, and it does set a local proxy. However, normally HTTP and HTTPs proxy service live on the same port, and going through their docs, I haven't found any evidence that they expect HTTPs to be proxied via 443.

Also, the exception call stack shows that whatever listens on port 443 expects raw SSL, and is most likely getting a proxy CONNECT method.

Comment: When I run the server in record mode, its listens on port 53, 80 and 443. So I configured HTTPS proxy for port 443, otherwise HTTPS requests are ignored.

Comment: I had a look at the source - I can't see the module handling CONNECT tunnels anywhere. When you set a proxy on HTTPs on any port, the browser will issue a CONNECT, which the proxy needs to process ahead of the SSL handshake. It does not look like `web-page-replay` does any of that - it just forwards the data as is to the SSL layer which rejects it.
Might best to contact the author.

Comment: Tried posting on multiple mailing lists already, but got no replies. The chromium telemetry project uses WPR too. I'm looking at telemetry code to see how they are recording HTTPS websites.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you're stuck. I'm a bit interested in this tool, so might install it myself and get to the bottom of how it's meant to do HTTPs filtering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71969/discussion-between-akshay-aurora-and-romank).

Answer (score 0):

As I see python's implementation of WebPageReplay is deprecated now, so you can use Go implementation https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/blob/master/web_page_replay_go/README.md

Developers suggest to use following Chrome(and all Chromium-like browsers) command line argument to bypass TLS checking by browser:

```
--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=PhrPvGIaAMmd29hj8BCZOq096yj7uMpRNHpn5PDxI6I=
```

where `PhrPvGIaAMmd29hj8BCZOq096yj7uMpRNHpn5PDxI6I=` it's a subject of certificate supplied with WebPageReplay which is used by default for all your domains recorded in wpr archive.

For other browsers which are not supported `--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list` you can implement generation certificates on the fly or pre-generation of by domain names in wpr archive.